# how to get local variables of a method from another class

Tags: java, methods, reflection, local-variables

I have two classes A and B
A class contains a method which has some of the local variables.
now I want to fetch a particular variable's data type in the B class. 
can you please help me with this.

I researched about java reflection. but I found that I can not achieve this by using reflection, as local variables are stored in stack at the runtime. And reflection can only fetch instance or class variables.

```
for example,

class A{
     method1(){
         variable1;
     }
}
class B{
      method 2(){
           fetch variable1;
       }
}
```

I want the data type of variable1 as a result.

Is there any way to achieve it using mocking or something?

Comment: you can't. there is a reason those variables are local variables.

Comment: You can get local variable when you return it from that method or it a global variable

Comment: You can't, variable 1 is a Local Variable therefore is destroyed once method1 is completed and only has scope in method1.

Comment: That goal makes no sense. You might not be aware that after your .java files are compiled, local variables don't exist anymore. They've been replaced with binary instructions that deal with the stack.

Comment: @Jaja Java doesn't have global variables. whatever you return is not the local variable, it's a value. now, assuming he is talking about code he can't alter, he can't just add a return type and statement.

Comment: @Stultuske I mean class variable

Comment: @jaja yes, I can't alter the code.

Comment: @Shweta that variable doesn't exist outside of the running of that method, so you would be trying to get the value of a non-existent variable

Comment: The local variables of a method only exist while that method is executing. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your support.
I found the answer myself.
I can do this via Java Regex Concept.
As I know a little about the variable's naming pattern,
So I am planning to parse the class1.java file and first will try pattern matching the method name and then the variables name.
So that I will get the line on which the variable is declared.
for example, if my variable is object,
     String abc=new String();

I will try regex like,  String regex=".*=new.*().*"

So this will fulfill my purpose.
Thanks again for helping.